# Typecasting int to char *

Tags: c, structure, typecasting-operator

Following definition of structure is defined in one of my header file

```
typedef struct REMDEV_ADDR {
UINT8    addr[DEVICE_ADDR_SIZE];
} RemDev_Addr;

typedef RemDev_Addr BTDEV_ADDR;
```

Now I have following function which I want to use.

```
 hci_acl_connect(UCHAR *   bd_addr,UINT16 *  handle);
```

So I made a global instance of the above structure in my c file

```
BTDEV_ADDR hsu_addr
```

and calling the function like this

```
hci_acl_connect((unsigned char *)&hsu_addr,&cont_hand);
```

Is typecasting is correct "(unsigned char *)&hsu_addr" ?

Comment: If `UCHAR` is the same type as `UINT8` on your compiler + platform, then try replacing `(unsigned char *)&hsu_addr` with just `hsu_addr.addr`. Otherwise post a *lot* more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Your variable resides on stack, but you need to provide a pointer, so you use `&your_var`. You need a pointer to `UCHAR`, so you cast: `(UCHAR *)&your_var`.

The casting itself is OK, but we don't know what `UCHAR *   bd_addr` is supposed to represent. Perhaps you should pass `your_var.addr` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the function to do something with the array `addr` in the structure, then there is no need for the casting. Just pass the `addr` member:

```
hci_acl_connect(hsu_addr.addr, &cont_hand);
```

That's assuming that both `UINT8` and `UCHAR` are both aliases of `unsigned char` (which seems like a safe assumption).

Comment: but hci_acl_connect(UCHAR *   bd_addr,UINT16 *  handle);
Its first argument required a char pointer

Comment: @Abhinav, you should probably refresh the page to see the latest edit to this answer

Comment: @Abhinav Unless e.g. `short` is 8 bits on your system, an `unsigned char` seems like the only reasonable way to define both `UINT8` and `UCHAR`, which means both types are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Casting from any other pointer type to a `char *` or `unsigned char *` is safe because `char` has the least strict alignment requirements, that is, it can be located at any address. It will also not break the strict aliasing rule.

The inverse, however, is undefined behaviour. A larger type will usually have stricter alignment requirements and that will potentially result in an attempt to do an operation at a misaligned address. The new pointer could also possibly alias the old one and that would potentially mislead the compiler when doing optimisations.